# How to get an array from a pre defined html radio input

Tags: php, html

I am working on a calculator for storage capability.
There are 3 pre defined brands of storage systems. These brands all have 8 different sized storage units.

Ex.     `$storage_size = array( 67.60, 135.20, 85.28, 170.56, 104, 208, 124.80, 249.60);`

User should put in the desired amount of storagecapability

```
  <input type="text" name="storage">
```

and my calculator reads it

```
  $storagecapacity = $_POST["storage"];
```

The code for the calculators works fine, the interface however bothers me.
Now in my interface, i would prefer to have 3 radio buttons with the name of the brand.

Selecting that one button would then send the array of sizes of that lift to my calculator.

My question is, how do i send a pre-defined array to my php calculator by selecting one of three radiobuttons?

Thanks ahead.

Ive tried to create an array like this.

```
<input type="radio" name="brand[]" value="100, 150, 160, 170">
<input type="radio" name="brand[]" value="110, 160, 160, 170">
<input type="radio" name="brand[]" value="120, 170, 160, 170">
```

Combined with

```
$Storagebrand = array($_POST["brand[]"]);
```

Unfortunaly it didnt seem to work.

i Expect to get a pre defined array send from my HTMLform to my PHPcalculator

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the values correctly, there is an additional `"`, please remove them so

```
value=""100, 150, 160, 170">
```

should be

```
 value="100, 150, 160, 170">
```

Comment: Sorry, edited it. Still getting the folowing error: Warning: Division by zero in (line where the array is being used)

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` and check the values that are being posted.. I hope the `action='post'` in form

Comment: maybe you need convert string to float or int type

Comment: ( [storage] => 300 [brand] => Array ( [0] => 100, 150, 160, 170, 50, 60, 70, 80 )  Seems like its sending the whole bunch of data in 1 spot in the array

Comment: `$_POST['brand']` has what you need.

Comment: Down the rabbit hole we go. $_POST['brand'] gives me: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\untitled1\test.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\User\PhpstormProjects\untitled1\test.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

Lines leading up to the fatal error

for ($i = 8; $i >= 0; $i--){

```
    $btotal = 0;
    $barray = array();

    for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++){
        $remaining = $storagecapacity - $btotal;
        $to_add = floor($remaining / $storagebrand[$j]);
```